# Matching only the beginning of a string in Python MULTILINE mode

Tags: python, regex

Python's [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) says this:

> `'^'`
>
> (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.

I want to use MULTILINE but I want to require a match at the beginning of the string (not just the beginning of a line). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: DO NOT remove the context information from the title. SO suggested pages don't include tag information.

Comment: From the "How to use tags" FAQ:  The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title. Your title does not follow this guideline. If everyone does this it makes it very difficult to understand what the question is about from the title because of the extra (redundant) data in the title.

Comment: This has been debated on Meta (can't remember where). My position is leave the title alone. It's my question, and it's a pet peeve of mine that I waste time clicking through links because they don't tell me that it's Javascript or C# instead of Python. Until SO decides they are going to include tag information alongside the suggested links, I will continue to include context information in the titles of my questions.

Comment: debated or no, the guidelines are pretty clear on the subject. Also the tag information is included in the general list, and in the suggested and related links are suggested and related based on (in large part) the tags. It's redundant and lowers the signal to noise ratio

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267695/matching-only-the-beginning-anchor-of-a-multiline-string](Matching only the beginning anchor of a multiline string) is Javascript, and it's in the related list of questions shown (to me at least) on this page.

Comment: You would prefer that the entire list started with "PYTHON:" "python:" "python---" "Help with Python:" etc?

Comment: I don't care how they indicate it, I just want to get some context information. And FWIW they are *GUIDELINES*.

Comment: @JasonS given that you're talking about regex syntax, which isn't unique to Python, why would it matter if the answer was on a question tagged with a different language? This is kind of surprising behaviour for someone in your position, frankly.

Comment: Because each of the languages have their own individual implementation quirks.

Comment: I'm getting back to work. stribizhev has done me the valuable service of answering two questions I couldn't figure out on my own; the rest of this quibbling about titles is just getting me pissed off.

Comment: So your real issue is that the suggested and related links shouldn't cross contaminate questions from other languages. I agree with you (mostly). But that doesn't make the issues with the signal/noise in putting tags in posts justified.

Comment: Also fwiw the answer is the same in Ruby and probably some other languages. So in this case it might make sense to link to other languages.

Comment: @JasonS would have been worth finding out if that was the case first, surely? Or just searching the Python docs page for *"start of the string"*? You're the one acting like an asshole here, don't try taking the high road now you've got your answer. You might be getting back to work but your laziness wastes other people's time, too.

Comment: @JasonS: then why not focus on the things that matter and are worth getting upset about? The community has already decided this one: please keep the tags out of the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `\A` anchor that matches the start of string unambiguously.

Check the [*Regular Expression Syntax*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> **\A**
>   Matches only at the start of the string.

Comment: ah, cool. Somehow I missed seeing that. It would be nice if the documentation for `^` referenced the `\A` pattern.

Comment: Right, there are a lot of such issues with the docs. Like `re.MULTILINE` won't work with `re.match`, this is also lost somewhere there.

Comment: "`re.MULTILINE` won't work with `re.match`" -- really? yikes, that's kind of important.

Comment: Well, I might have re-worded it. It is mentioned in [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), not in [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) section: *Note that even in `MULTILINE` mode, `re.match()` will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.*

Comment: Oh. Maybe I should have just used `re.match` then. For some reason I thought it tried to match the entire string (anchors at both beginning and end)